# How to fix "Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Component)" error?

Tags: ubuntu-19.04

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Remove the list -> sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
2. Retry to import it again, but first check if you have everything installed that is required (for example you could use *lsb_release* in your URL or similar things)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what I do, I still get this error:
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-obs.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

running on the windows store ubuntu version codename: bionic